# Expose any database as RESTful web service

Tags: xml, json, web-services, rest

How can one expose any database as a json/xml web service. There are many tutorials available for writing web services for given database however how it can be made generic so the code can be used to generate web service for any database, at least the CRUDs (create, read, update and delete).

Here is what I can think of.

- Use a database library which support multiple databases. Something
  similar to [ADODB](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/).
- App fetches the list of tables (objects) and generates CRUD web services for each table. Or may be a generic RESTful client and server can be used for the same.

At the same time, I am wondering if there are any tools available for that which I am not aware of and can save all this trouble.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your business case, I have to say this sounds like a Bad Idea to me.

Comment: Business case is simple - developing a tool which allows you to expose any database via web services starting with CRUD operations supporting both json and xml. All user need to do is provide credentials of the database and optionally ability to select tables and fields for GET, POST and PUT requests.